# Django Aggregation for Goals

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm saving every Sale in a Store. I want to use aggregation to sum all of the sales in a month for every store. And i want to filter the stores that reach the goal (100.000$).

I've already came up with a solution using python and a list. But i wanted to know if there is a better solution using only the ORM.

```
Sales model

Store        Sale     Date
Store A      5.000    11/01/2014
Store A      3.000    11/01/2014
Store B      1.000    15/01/2014
Store C      8.000    17/01/2014
...
```

The result should be this:

```
Month: January

Store   Amount
A       120.000
B       111.000
C       150.000

and discard
D        70.000
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can we see code sample?

Comment: To be clear, you want to filter out all stores with sales over 100, and then add up the total sales from those stores?

Comment: I want to add up the total sales from a store (every store). And then show the stores with sales over 100.000.

I just added the Sales model in the question to be clear.

Comment: Hard to give you code to use in the ORM when you don't show your actual models...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other suggested methods discard a lot of data that takes a fraction of a second to load, and that could be useful later on in your code. Hence this answer.

Instead of querying on the `Sales` object, you can query on the `Store` object. The query is roughly the same, except for the relations:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

stores = Store.objects.filter(sales__date__month=month, sales__date__year=year) \
    .annotate(montly_sales=Sum('sales__amount')) \
    .filter(montly_sales__gte=100000) \
    # optionally prefetch all `sales` objects if you know you need them
    .prefetch_related('sales') 

>>> [s for s in stores]
[
    <Store object 1>,
    <Store object 2>,
    etc.
]
```

All `Store` objects have an extra attribute `montly_sales` that has the total amount of sales for that particular month. By filtering on month and year before annotating, the annotation only uses the filtered related objects. Note that the `sales` attribute on the store still contains *all* sales for that store.

With this method, all store attributes are easily accessible, unlike when you use `.values` to group your results.

Answer (score 2):

Without a good look at your models the best I can do is pseudocode.  But I would expect you need something along the lines of

```py
from django.db.models import Sum
results = Sales.objects.filter(date__month=month, date__year=year)
results = results.values('store')
results = results.annotate(total_sales=Sum(sale))
return    results.filter(total_sales__gt=100)
```

Basically, what we're doing is using django's aggregation capabilities to compute the Sum of sales for each store.  Per django's [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/aggregation/#values), we can use the `values` function to group our results by distinct values in a given field.

- In line 2 we filter our sales to only sales from this month.
- In line 3, we limit our results to the values for field store.
- In line 4, we annotate each result with the Sum of all sales from the
  original query.
- In line 5, we filter on that annotation, limiting the returned results to stores with `total_sales` greater than 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to handle this. Since I do not know your model structure, That is an average guess

```py
from djnago.db.models import Sum
Sales.objects.filter(date__month=3, date__year=2014).values('store').annotate(monthly_sale=Sum('sale'))
```

That will return you a Queryset of Stores and their monthly sales like:

```py
>> [
    {"store": 1, "monthly_sale": 120.000},
    {"store": 2, "monthly_sale": 100.000},
    ...
]
```

In above query assume you have:

- Sales model have a `Date` or `Datetime` field named `date`
- Your `Sale` model have a ForeignKey relation to `Store`
- Your `Sales` model have a numeric field (`Integer`, `Decimal` etc.) named `sale`

In your resulting QuerySet, `store` is the id of your store record. But since it is a ForeigKey, you can use relation to get its name etc...

```py
Sales.objects.filter(date__month=3, date__year=2014).values('store__name').annotate(monthly_sale=Sum('sale'))


>> [
    {"store__name": "Store A", "monthly_sale": 120.000},
    {"store__name": "Store B", "monthly_sale": 100.000},
    ...
]
```